# App engine 404 Error for readiness check even with increased app_start_timeout_sec

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

First off, I would like to state that I have scoured SO for a solution, yet nothing worked for me...

I am trying to deploy a flask server on App engine, yet I always get a 404 Error with `/readiness_check failReason:"null"`

This is my app.yaml (yes, I did increase the `app_start_timeout_sec`)

```
    # yaml config for custom environment that uses docker
    runtime: custom
    env: flex
    service: test-appengine
    # change readiness check ; 
    # rediness failure leads to 502 Error
    readiness_check:
      path: "/readiness_check"
      check_interval_sec: 5
      timeout_sec: 4
      failure_threshold: 2
      success_threshold: 2
      app_start_timeout_sec: 1800
```

And this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use the official Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.8-buster

# Install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .

# expose port 8080 for app engine
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.

# CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 main:app
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "-b", ":8080", "--timeout", "300"]
```

Finally, my `main.py` contains a very basic route, for the sake of the argument :

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def return_hello():
    return "Hello!"
```

Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Have been battling this issue for days now ... Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you still need to define the handler for your `readiness_check` (you're getting 404 which means route not found).

See this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-debug-an-unresponsive-app-on-gcp-a1c00499e2cb) for an example

Comment: That actually seems to help ! These errors are not present anymore (although I have others). In no docs is there a mention of this route (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/flexible/hello_world). Thanks a lot !